# Verifying if there are numeric values in data frame in R

Tags: r

How can I check if there are any columns in the dataframe are of type numeric in R?

I want to be able to check for the data set iris. It should return true because there are 4 numeric values in this data set.

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`, we can use `sapply` with `is.numeric` - `sapply` loop over the columns, `is.numeric` returns TRUE if the columns is `numeric` and FALSE if not, then wrap with `any` to return a single TRUE/FALSE (i.e. if there are any TRUE values, it returns TRUE)

```
any(sapply(iris, is.numeric))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` option that counts number of numeric columns:

```r
library(dplyr)
length(select_if(iris,is.numeric))
#> [1] 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>